# How to show that the matrix $[[0, I],[-M^{-1}K_p, -M^{-1}K_d]]$ has eigenvalues with negative real parts

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I\\
-M^{-1}K_p & -M^{-1}K_d
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where M is a positive definite matrix and $K_p$ and $K_d$ are diagonal matrices with only positive entries. Can we prove that the matrix only has eigenvalues with negative real parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & I\\ -M^{-1}K_p&  -M^{-1}K_d\end{bmatrix}$$ let $Av=\lambda v.$ Then for $v=(x,y)$ we have
$$ y=\lambda x,\qquad -M^{-1}K_p\,x-
 M^{-1}K_d\,y=\lambda y$$ Thus $$\lambda^2\,x+\lambda\,(M^{-1}K_d\,x)+M^{-1}K_p\,x=0$$ which gives
$$\lambda^2\,(Mx)+\lambda\,(K_d\,x) +K_p\,x=0$$ Next  $$\langle Mx,x\rangle\,\lambda^2+ \langle K_d\,x,x\rangle\,\lambda +\langle K_p\,x,x\rangle=0$$  We obtained a quadratic equation with positive coefficients. Thus both roots have
negative  real part.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a negative sign, please see the current version.

Comment: That's a clever proof! Thanks!